# Record webcam video and audoi on server using Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, video, audio, webcam, record

I need a SilverLight application that can capture the webcam video and audio and save it on the server as video which can later be viewed by some video player. I have found some good examples of recording webcam using SilverLight like [link1](http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-4/photobooth/) and mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/10/silverlight-4-more-on-capturing-video-from-webcams.aspx as link2 that actually saves the video locally on isolated storage. Link1 saves video and audio while link2 saves only video and it converts it to weird .avi format (it can be played using only QuickTime player). I also guess it would not be much of a problem to take the stream to the server and save the video there.

The major problem that occurs is the size of the video. It is simply unacceptably big (otherwise I would use link1 solution). I tried converting it to some know format using command line FFMpeg. I was not able to convert the video from link1 at all, but I successfully managed to convert video from link2 to .flv format having nice and acceptable file size. One problem though, link2 doesn't include audio and I can't use it without audio.

So, I guess the problem is simple, record the video from local webcam to server and play it later, but the video needs to have acceptable size and possibly well known format. Any extra tools for video conversion like FFMpeg or Expression Encoder are available, but I would need to access them from code (command line) so they need to have command line API.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Can you please give a hint/link on how to convert video from that link2 to .flv format? Mine is almost as your case except that audio is not "required". But the file size of the video from link2 is simply not acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Red5 Server, thus saving the videos on server in .flv format. I used free http://www.red5-recorder.com/ video recorder, but did some custom tweaks for purposes of the project. I must note that the video quality is not so good.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [Streaming Video Recorder](http://www.streaming-video-recorder.com/) to record webcame video, it can just record screen video and the recorded video's quality is as original one which you see on webpage.The videos are save in WMV format and I think it's easy to find a video converter out there to help you convert it to other deisred video format.